# Error while trying to run 'make' command on darknet YOLO library on a Mac

Tags: macos, makefile, darknet

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/utils.c -o obj/utils.o

./src/utils.c:29:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_gettime' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
    ^

./src/utils.c:29:19: fatal error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLOCK_REALTIME'
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
              ^
```

> 1 warning and 1 error generated. make: *** [obj/utils.o] Error 1

Answer (score 1):

The `clock_gettime` function is not available on MacOS.  So you'll have to rewrite the code to use a different method.